# Sending keystrokes to a Flash/Silverlight app embedded in a webbrowser control (mostly done)

Tags: c#, vb.net, silverlight, winapi, sendkeys

**NOTE: This doesn't seem to necessarily apply to Silverlight only, I've read people have the same problems with Flash, so keep that in mind.**

I'm trying to write a program that will control Netflix through my own buttons (for now, eventually it will be extended to a mobile remote control app), by sending hotkeys directly to it using the windows api.

- I am able to retrieve the actual window handle used by the Netflix Silverlight player.
- I am able to send keystrokes to specified window handles (using the `TranslateMessage` function in win api)
- But I cannot, for some reason, get the netflix player to recognize any keystroke I send.
- I have tried using the `SetFocus` function in the win api before attempting to send keypresses and that doesn't help.

What I need to figure out, is why it's differentiating keys sent via api calls, from physical keyboard key presses.

Here's how I have things set up (window class names for reference):

> Form1 (`WindowsForms10.Window.8.app.0.33c0d9d`)
>
> > WebBrowser Control (`Shell DocObject View`)
> >
> > > HTML Page (`Internet Explorer_Server`)
> > >
> > > > Embedded Silverlight player (`MicrosoftSilverlight`)

I was wondering if someone might be able to offer some suggestions.  Thanks very much in advance.. hopefully someone can help get me through this.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Send keyboard and mouse events to Flash Movie](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2314268/send-keyboard-and-mouse-events-to-flash-movie)

Comment: possibly send keystrokes to the browser itself, or some parent window, instead? or maybe using the keybd_event instead?

Answer (score 0):

I tried to send `KeyEvents` to a flash application in C# (I wanted to 'hack' the griefing game called "CLOP").

I noticed this didn't work. I can however perfectly send `KeyEvents` to the browser itself but the flash plugin seems to ignore these even after acquiring focus.

I suspect this isn't possible because of security measures.

I found the following thread here on StackOverflow that explained a bit more about this (this one is about flash as well)
[Send keyboard and mouse events to Flash Movie](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2314268/send-keyboard-and-mouse-events-to-flash-movie)